# error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, cuda, nvcc

How can I force gcc to look in /usr/cuda/local/include for cuda_runtime.h?

I'm attempting to compile a CUDA application with a C wrapper. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

I've successfully compiled my CUDA application into a .so with the following command:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_11 -o libtest.so --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC main.cu
```

When I try and compile my c wrapper file with the following command:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o main -L. -ltest main.c
```

I receive the error:

```
error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory
```

I've verified that cuda_runtime.h is in fact present in /usr/local/cuda/include

Comment: I assume you mean /usr/local/cuda/include.  Did you try adding a -I switch to your gcc command line?  For example:  gcc -std=c99 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -o main -L. -ltest main.c

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please post it as an answer to your question. Then accept it or I will upvote the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there any option to make it work without adding -l? A library gives me this error

Answer (score 17):

If you are using CMake

```
find_package(CUDA  REQUIRED)
include_directories("${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

Comment: This is depecrated in modern CMake, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75559127/1150303, below

Answer (score 12):

Using an -I switch allowed gcc to find the cuda_runtime.h file:

```
gcc -std=c99 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -o main -L. -ltest main.c
```

Answer (score 12):

We were using CMake but it still wasn't able to find the header files (maybe it is the CMake version that couldn't find the directory `./targets/x86_64-linux/include` or because we have multiple CUDA versions). Setting [`CPATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409061/define-include-directory-path-for-h-centos) and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` fixed it for us:

```
export CPATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include:$CPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This fixed the issue and can be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-isystem /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include` to CXX_INCLUDES in flags.make file.

Answer (score 0):

Using modern CMake https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/packages/CUDA.html - `CUDA` has become a CMake language just like `CXX`:

```
check_language(CUDA)
if(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
    enable_language(CUDA)

    # to tell your code it was found via #ifdef USE_CUDA:
    add_definitions(-DUSE_CUDA)    

    include_directories("${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")
endif()
```

and after definition of executable or library don't forget cuda arch version(s)

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "35;50;72")
```